# R: date/time YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ formate

Tags: r, datetime-format

How can I change the type of variable data$timestamp from char to date format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ date/time in R ? I'm willing to keep all information within this format.

```
2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `as.POSIXct` to have an object of class `"POSIXct"`.

```
x <- "2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z"

op <- options("digits.secs" = 3)

d <- as.POSIXct(x, tz = "UTC", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
d
#[1] "2014-04-06 18:42:05.822 UTC"

class(d)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

format(d, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "2014-04-06T18:42:05.822"
```

See `help("strptime")` for data time formats.

**Note.**
`as.POSIXct` and `strptime` may give different results, depending on the time zone.

```
as.POSIXct(x, tz = "UTC", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
#[1] "2014-04-06 18:42:05.822 UTC"
strptime(x, tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
#[1] "2014-04-06 18:42:05.823 UTC"
```

The last digit is off by 1.

Comment: when i apply this fomat on whole column such as data$Timestamp <- format(d, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS3") then it change type of date from POSIXct  to char > str(data)
'data.frame':   2538 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ SessionID: int  13307 21076 27813 8398 23118 12256 28799 11457 7542 19261 ...
 $ Timestamp: chr  "2014-04-06T18:42:05.822" "2014-04-03T15:27:48.118" "2014-04-04T09:10:14.357" "2014-04-03T23:39:20.244" ...
 $ ItemID   : int  214684513 214718203 214716928 214826900 214838180 214717318 214821307 214537967 ...
 $ Price    : int  0 0 0 0 0 .....

Comment: @mairakhan If you want to keep the `T` it will always be an object of class `"character"`. If you want a `POSIXct` you must get rid of the `T`.

Comment: can you plz explain your i cant understand. is there any way to convert it into date format from char

Comment: @mairakhan The first two lines of code above transform from character to date format. They transform the character variable `x` to a POSIXct `d`.

Comment: yeah i know sir that first two lines convert it into POSIXct format but it didnt take sub seconds data$Timestamp <-as.POSIXct(data$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
> str(data)
'data.frame':   2538 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X        : int  1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ SessionID: int  13307 21076 27813 8398 23118 12256...
 $ Timestamp: POSIXct, format: "2014-04-06 18:42:05" "2014-04-03 15:27:48" "2014-04-04 09:10:14" "2014-04-03 23:39:20"..
 $ ItemID   : int  214684513 214718203 214716928 214826900 214838180 214717318 214821307 214537967 ...
 $ Price    : int  0 0 0 0 0.. i need subseconds :(

Comment: @mairakhan You can solve that  by setting `options("digits.secs" = 3)`. See the edit.

Comment: thank you sooo much sir for ur great help thanks alot :)